# ui-sref not respond anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the `ui-sref` for making a link, but it's not respond anything

Here's the code for the `ui-sref`

```
<a class="col col-40" ng-repeat="table in tables" style="background:{{table.warna}}" ui-sref="app.go({tableID:table.fstRoomNo})">{{table.fstRoomName}}<br/>{{table.fsiStatus}}</a>
```

and here the `app.js` config section

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "views/auth/login.html",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "views/app/side-menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "views/app/home.html",
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.go', {
    url: "/go/:tableID",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        controller: 'GoCtrl'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      detail_data: function(TabelService, $ionicLoading, $stateParams) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Loading table status ...'
        });
        //alert($stateParams.tableID);
        var tableID = $stateParams.tableID;
        return TabelService.getDetailTable(tableID);
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

Comment: Hoping this is a spelling error while writing the code here `TabelService` should be `TableService`

Comment: Oh god, you're right. I'm misspell it.

Thank you to make me realize @SatejS

Comment: Is it working fine now?

Comment: It's kind a silly. But it's working now.

I'm asking in here because I'm not getting any response or log

Comment: Yes, you should have got some error in your console.Either way, would it be alright if i posted this as an answer , so it can be selected and the question closed, or are there any other issues?

Comment: for the routing, it's working now.

but may I ask you other thing ? Got the problem with $http.post

Comment: Yep, you can either post that here by modifying the question
, or post another question.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know the $http.post problem as well.

Comment: I think i must wait for 90 minutes before I can post a question again @SatejS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer after the comment above solved the issue.

Regarding the issue with the routing, it is probably because of the spelling error below.

```
resolve: {
      detail_data: function(TabelService, $ionicLoading, $stateParams) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Loading table status ...'
        });
        //alert($stateParams.tableID);
        var tableID = $stateParams.tableID;
        return TabelService.getDetailTable(tableID);
      }
    }
```

Where `TabelService` should be spelled as `TableService`